# How to derive the variance of a weighted moving average?

Tags: time-series, standard-deviation, exponential-smoothing, moving-average

I have a problem understanding a piece of a paper. Greatly appreciate any hint or help.  It says:

> A sensor records $Z(i)$ at intervals of 1 second and calculates
>   background values $U(i)$ using formula:
>
> $U(i)=RU(i-1)+(1-R)Z(i)$,
>
> where R is a constant factor and $U(0)$ is computed from pre-measurement
>   data.

Now, any idea if this formula is famous? Is it a two-term Gaussian mixture noise?
Then, it says exactly like this:

> The variance $δU(i)$ of these values is computed from the calculated
>   values $U(i)$:
>
> $δU(i)=k \sqrt{\frac{U(i)}{T}}$
>
> where k is sigma factor and T is the given measuring time.

I have no idea how the variance became something like that. I understand the term T and the sqrt function but the overall formula, no idea.

Comment: Please update the title to something more informative and, if possible, give a citation to the paper in question. The calculation $U(i)$ is an [exponentially weighted moving average](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moving_average#Exponential_moving_average) of $Z(i)$.

Comment: Exponentially Weighted Moving Average, exactly. But, how the variance became a function of that form? I'm afraid, I don't have the whole paper, I just know that this method is used for measuring some background radio frequency.

Comment: For future reference, it's not generally considered polite to cross-post to [several](http://able2know.org/topic/177306-1) [different](http://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20110912102743AAj2D5l) forums simultaneously.

Comment: Is $T$ the total number of samples? And what is $k$? I don't see how the variance is likely related to the *square root* of $T$. I think some more context is needed here to answer your question.

Comment: @cardinal It's ok to cross-post, just not to multiple SE forums (because we have a migration mechanism).  However, it is expected that useful information received on *any* of those forums will be shared on *all* of them.  It also is considered polite to inform people when cross-posting.

Comment: Yes, T is the total number of samples. It's been said that k is the margin of statistical safety, has a value between 1 and 10. But it doesn't make sense to me. I believe k should be related to R, not a simple constant which comes from a distribution. When I saw the relation i was thinking of the standard deviation of mean. That's how the sqrt part and T made sense to me.

Comment: I'd start by solving the recurrent relation $U(i)$.