# Standard deviations and confidence intervals (weighted) running average

Tags: confidence-interval, mean, weighted-mean, fourier-transform, convolution

My question is related to [this one](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/15475/how-to-derive-the-variance-of-a-weighted-moving-average). I am calculating averages, actually as many as I have samples because I calculate a running average, and for equal weighting I know how to calculate the $95\%$ CI, with $\mu\pm1.96*\sigma_{original}$. However there are two things that I dont know how to do. Can I get the $\sigma_{original}$ from the same method (convolution through Fourier transform)? How do I calculate the $95\%$ CI if the weighting is not equal (so if I convolute with a window that is not flat)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Im quite happy I found something of an answer. Its relatively straightforward and not very different from calculating your running average in the first place. However I only figured out the running part, not the weighted part. Although the following equation (found [here](http://www.johndcook.com/standard_deviation.html)) is not always the best way to get your standard deviation, in this case it helped me. [This](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/9428-moving-window-standard-deviation) Matlab function helped me find it. That function assumes that your signal is not periodic however so I still needed to make my own.

[image]

The first term inside the brackets ($ \sum x_i^2 $) you get with the convolution $f^{2}\ast g$, the second part ($ [\sum x_i]^2 $) by the convolution $(f \ast g)^{2}$. Where $f$ is the signal and $g$ is the window. The squares are pointwise. Then apply the rest of the formula and youre golden. Note that $f \ast g$ is your running average which you already computed.

This straightforward implementation is only valid for periodic signals and I think it is also only valid for non-weighted averages / flat windows. For non periodic signals you need padding and for weighted averages you need to change the formula for $s$. How to change this I still dont know. If I ever figure it out Ill add it here.